# If people who work at 100% of a program, do the full program in 42 weeks, how many weeks does someone who works at 60% capacity need?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If people who work at 100% of a program, do the full program in 42 weeks, how many weeks does someone who works at 60% capacity need?

I said 75.6 weeks and here's how I got it:

1. people who work at 100% do 42 weeks
2. people who work at 50% capacity do 84 weeks (double it)
3. halfway between 50 and 100 is 75% and halfway between 42 and 84 is 63, so people who work at 75% capacity do 63 weeks
4. halfway between 50% and 75% is 62.5% and halfway between 84 weeks and 63 weeks is 73.5 weeks, so people who work at 62.5% capacity do 73.5 weeks
5. Someone who works at 60% capacity does 75.6 weeks (or round up to 76 weeks)

Everyone else I asked is giving an answer of 70 weeks (they are doing 42 divided by 0.6).

I feel like I am right and they are using the wrong equation. Can you either tell me the equation that will give me my answer (and vindicate me) or call me an idiot and I will accept that, please?

Comment: You're interpolating between points 1 and 2.  By that reasoning, someone working at 0% capacity would finish in 126 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

What is percentage? $100\%=1,50\%=.5$ so we can see a percentage is just a fraction of a whole($1$).

Working at $.6$ capacity means slowing down by $\frac1{.6}$ for the whole period. This means the amount of time will be $42\times\frac1{.6}=70$

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate everyone chiming in and I also appreciate your sensitivity re: not bashing me into the ground for being so stupid.

Comment: @eri I hope some answers have helped. I feel stupid in mathematics very often, and I am in my third year majoring it! Nothing stupid about your question at all

Answer (score 1):

It is, $42 \text{wk} \times \dfrac{100\%}{60\%} = 70\text{wk}$, as they said.

> 3.halfway between $50$ and $100$ is $75\%$ and halfway between $42$ and $84$ is $63$, so people who work at $75\%$ capacity do $63$ weeks

People who work at $75\%$ capacity take $56$ weeks.  $$56 \;=\; 42 \times\dfrac{100\%}{75\%}$$

Your method (called linear interpolation) will not work because there is not a linear relation between effort and time.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, you yourself have stated that one working at 50% needs 84 weeks. (You got this by multiplying 100/50 and 42)

So similarly, one working at 60% needs 42*(10/6)=70 weeks.

Also, one working at 75% needs 42*(100/75)= 56 weeks; you make the mistake here itself, hence your calculations for 60% are wrong.